# Is there a clean way to combine multi-case and single-case switch's in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, switch-statement

```js
switch (z) {
  case 'a':
    x = 'this';
    y = 1;
    break;
  case 'b':
    x = 'that';
    y = 2;
    break;
  case 'c':
    x = 'that';
    y = 3;
    break;
}
```

In the 'b' and 'c' cases I'm setting `x = 'that'` for both, but `y` is different for each.

Obviously 1 duplicated line is fairly irrelevant but my real code gets quite a bit more complex so it would be 'nice' to not duplicate it.

`x` can't be set before the switch to 'that' and then overwritten by other cases, because the object it's being set to may not exist depending on the case.

Converting the switch to if/else does remove the duplication but is there a way to do it with a switch?

```js
if (z == 'a') {
  x = 'this';
  y = 1;
} else { // or else if (z == 'b' || z == 'c') if necessary
  x = 'that';
  if (z == 'b') {
    y = 2;
  } else if (z == 'c') {
    y = 3;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way seems to be combing a multi-case switch with if/else

```js
switch (z) {
    case 'a':
    x = 'this';
    y = 1;
    break;
  case 'b':
  case 'c':
    x = 'that';
    if (z == 'b') {
      y = 2;
    }
    if (z == 'c') {
      y = 3;
    }
    break;
  case 'd':
  case 'e':
    x = 'foo';
    if (z == 'd') {
      y = 4;
    }
    if (z == 'e') {
      y = 5;
    }
    break;
}
```

It keeps the clarity of the switch, the if/else removes duplicated code, and it's easily expandable as show by the 'd'/'e' cases.

Or repeat the switch inside.

```js
switch (z) {
    case 'a':
    x = 'this';
    y = 1;
    break;
  case 'b':
  case 'c':
    x = 'that';
    switch (z) {
      case 'b':
        y = 2;
        break;
      case 'c':
        y = 3;
        break
    }
    break;
  case 'd':
  case 'e':
    x = 'foo';
    switch (z) {
      case 'd':
        y = 4;
        break;
      case 'e':
        y = 5;
        break
    }
    break;
}
```